# How do I change a header cell when the page changes?

Tags: itext, pdfptable

I have a `PdfPTable` in my document being written using iTextSharp. There are some header rows which get repeated whenever the table overflows to another page. One of those rows contains a cell with some text, e.g. "John Doe".

What I want is for that text to change to "John Doe (continued)" on each subsequent page. From what I can tell, I need to do something in the `OnEndPage` event that somehow manipulates the instance of the header cell for that page, but I'm struggling to find out how exactly to find the cell in the written content and then manipulate it.

How do I achieve this goal?

Comment: I wonder why the downvote. Two in one day on unrelated questions. Seems a bit weird.

Answer (score 4):

After some trial and error, I was able to get a working solution. I implemented the `IPdfCellEvent` which declares a single method, `CellLayout`. As per the [iText documentation](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/index.html?com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfPCellEvent.html), this is called after the cell has been rendered, which means, the first time it is called it has rendered the cell for the very first page of the table. So, I use this call to add the extra text so that all subsequent renderings will include the additional text.

This is my interface implementation:

```
private class ContinuedCellEvent : IPdfPCellEvent
{
    public void CellLayout( PdfPCell cell, Rectangle position, PdfContentByte[] canvases )
    {
        if ( !_continuationApplied )
        {
            // This is called AFTER cell rendering so this should set the cell for the next time it is rendered
            // which will always be on a continuation.
            cell.Phrase.Add( new Chunk( " Continued" ) );

            _continuationApplied = true;
        }
    }

    private bool _continuationApplied;
}
```

It is used when defining the cell:

```
cell.CellEvent = new ContinuedCellEvent();
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `onEndPage()` could work, but I would implement the `PdfPTableEventSplit` interface if I were you. I'd use a membervariable `cellContent` and set it to `"John Doe"` upon creating the event instance. I would draw the content of `cellContent` in the `tableLayout()` method and change its content to `"John Doe (continued)"` in the `splitTable()` method.

Try it out and share your code. If it works, others will be helped; if it doesn't, I'll take a look to see what goes wrong (but please understand that I'm not a C# developer; I wrote iText in Java; I had to hire people to port it to C#).

Comment: So, I was looking at this, but unfortunately, I cannot use this approach as we're using v4.1.2 of iTextSharp and as such, PdfPTableEventSplit is not available. I suspect this will work great if I had access to a newer version, but due to the AGPL terms, we cannot do that.

Comment: Ouch 31K reputation and willingly working with deprecated, obsolete software... How is that possible?

Comment: AGPL means we can't use it in our commercial software without open-sourcing the whole thing, which we can't do. So we're stuck with the last version prior to the application of AGPL.

Comment: That's the narrow interpretation of the AGPL. Plenty of your competitors buy a license to be released from the obligation to open source their whole product. That's only fair, isn't it?

Comment: Indeed. However, that's something that I do not have control of at the moment so I must work within the parameters of our current setup. Asi es la vida.